# Reusing EAX for two different arrays

Tags: assembly

I've been working on a hw assignment for my assembly class where we have to convert from F to C and then calculate the difference from the "Corrected" values and "Rounded" values. However, I cannot get my program to run properly when I try to reuse eax for the second array. I've been trying to figure out why this is causing a problem for my program but I have not been successful so far. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
EXTRN _printf:PROC

.STACK  4096                ; reserve 4096-byte stack

.DATA                       ; reserve storage for data
nbrArray DWORD -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
nbrC DWORD -23,-23,-22,-22,-21,-21,-20,-19,-19,-18,-18,-17,-17,-16,-16,-15,-14,-14,-13,-13,-12
nbrElts  DWORD  21
cTemp    DWORD   ?
mult     DWORD   5
div      DWORD   9
diff     DWORD   ?
corr     DWORD   ?


format1  BYTE  "Rounded C: %d", 0
format2  BYTE  " Corrected C: %d", 0
format3  BYTE  " Difference: %d", 10, 0



.CODE                       ; start of main program code
main    PROC            
    lea ebx, nbrArray       ; get address of nbrArray
    lea edx, nbrC           ; get address of nbrCorrect
    mov ecx, nbrElts        ; count := nbrElts

forLoop:
    mov  eax, [ebx]         ; mov value to eax
    add  ebx, 4             ; iterate thru array
    sub  eax, 32            ; F-32
    imul mul                ; (F-32)*5
    add  eax, 4             ; ((F-32)*5)+4          
    cdq
    idiv div                ; (((F-32)*5)+4)/9
    mov  cTemp, eax         ; Store celcius result

    mov  eax,  [edx]        ; mov value to eax
    add  edx, 4             ; iterate thru array
    mov  corr, eax                  ; store correct result
    sub  eax, cTemp         ; Calculate difference

    ;output: use printf("Rounded Up C: %d", cTemp)

    pusha
    push cTemp              
    push offset format1                     
    call _printf
    add esp, 8              
    popa            

    ;output: use printf(" Corrected C: %d", corr)
    pusha
    push corr               
    push offset format2                                     
    call _printf
    add esp, 8          
    popa

    loop forLoop

    mov  eax, 0
    ret

main   ENDP
END
```

This is the part that is causing the trouble. Specifically the first line, whenever I run my program:

```
mov  eax,  [edx]        ; mov value to eax
add  edx, 4             ; iterate thru array
mov  corr, eax              ; store correct result
```

Comment: What specifically is not working as you expected?

Comment: When I remove that second box of code my program works fine and prints out the converted F to C values, but when I add that box of code it compiles and when I run it the console freezes and stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop, you have to store & restore `edx`, since all the instructions `mul`, `div` and `cdq` use `edx` as an implicit secondary register. Thus you are not accessing the array you want to.

Two strategies to reuse *edx* are:
  1) **use stack**

```
push edx;
;; do something else, like
cdq
mul ebx
idiv ebp
...
pop edx
```

2) **dedicate a variable for the pointer** (*I'm using here an index instead*)

```
mov dword ptr [myIndex], 0    ;// Optionally initialize the variable
...
cdq

mov edx, [myIndex]            ;// Use which ever register that is available
inc dword ptr [myIndex], 1    ;// Post increment the index -- directly in memory
mov eax, [myArray + 4*edx]    ;// use 'SIB' addressing mode (Scale, Index, Base)
```

Comment: Could you explain more explicitly on what you mean by store & restore? In my mind, I am thinking like how you push a stored value from a register onto a stack to preserve it and then pop it off to restore it. Is that what pertains to this?

Comment: Yes. When the number of variables grows, it may be too complex to dedicate some register to a variable. It's also possible to place the variables to _local_ memory. Use e.g. `gcc -S` to disassemble a simple c routine to find where local variables are stored.

Comment: I used the stack technique, and it works now! Thanks a lot for explaining this to me. I wouldn't have been able to figure it out on my own.